# Allow an object's List(Of T) property to be amended but not replaced

Tags: vb.net

If I create an object like this...

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Property SomeList As New List(Of Int32)
End Class
```

...I can alter the list using the normal methods:

```
Dim s As New SomeClass()
s.SomeList.Add(123)
```

But, is it possible to allow the above access to the list, but prevent the whole list being replaced by another list instance?  For example, prevent this:

```
Dim s As New SomeClass()
Dim lst As New List(Of Int32)
lst.Add(1)
s.SomeList = lst ' <-- prevent a replacement list being passed
```

I notice that when using the `Net.MailMessage` class, there is a Property called `To` where this seems to have been applied.  I can add an email address to the list...

```
Dim mm as New MailMessage
mm.To.Add(New MailAddress("me@company.com"))
```

...but I cannot replace the `MailAddressCollection`:

```
Dim mm As MailMessage
Dim mc As MailAddressCollection
mm.To = mc ' Error: Property 'To' is 'ReadOnly'
```

How is this achieved please?  I tried to decompile the source of MailMessage but there is *so* much code I'm struggling to see how it is done.

Comment: Make the property `ReadOnly`. That said, it’s usually a bad idea to expose a whole list like that anyway. It’s better to put exactly those operations that you need to support into the API.

Comment: Okay great.  I thought adding `ReadOnly` would prevent the list items being modified.  How is `SomeClass.SomeList.Add` still able to do it's thing in this case?

Comment: I see that I cannot use shortcut properties when `ReadOnly` is applied.  So I assume the `Add` is actually that of the internal/private property?

Comment: Yes.  The consuming code gets access to the internal list and can add, sort, clear.  See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @EvilDr Even with the single line "shortcut" property, there is still a hidden private field that contains the List. ReadOnly means that the private field cannot be replaced with a new list (which is what you want), it doesn't stop the caller of the Property's Get clause from executing methods (like the Add method) that are exposed by the List.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I see in that page, *"DO NOT provide settable collection properties"*

Comment: Why won't VS2013 allow `Public ReadOnly Property SomeList As New List(Of Int32)`?  It insists on a `Get/Set` being written, but using the shortcut approach, the private list would actually be created in the same manner, resulting in exactly the same functionality but with less code.

Comment: @EvilDr Because Microsoft evidently doesn’t want to put too much effort into developing VB further. This trend has been observable for years now, where new features were half-assed, and, compared to C#) almost always crippled in their capabilities (there are some counter-examples, but not many). As somebody who has grown up with VB and has used VB.NET since the first unofficial beta version, I’d advise you to ditch VB and move to C# – Microsoft has clearly done the same.

Comment: @EvilDr I made a suggestion to Microsoft that they allow a single line ReadOnly property that could be initialised as in your example, or in the class's constructor (as you can with a ReadOnly field). The answer was that they intended to use the single line ReadOnly property syntax for some other purpose in the future. I don't remember what that purpose was.

Comment: Readonly  "Shortcut" properties are confirmed in VS 2015. See "readonly auto properties" at http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/new-improvement-of-C-Sharp-and-visual-basic-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Thanks Bradley, to quote the link, *"In Visual Basic, we have new features as in C#...ReadOnly auto-properties are a big favorite"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways..

```
Private _SomeList As New List(Of Int32)
Public ReadOnly Property SomeList As IList(Of Int32)
    Get
        Return _SomeList
    End Get
End Property
```

..as Konrad pointed out in the comments.  Having the property return the IList Interface instead of List is a style thing. If you run code analysis, it will suggest returning the IList instead of List.

That will prevent the caller from replacing the list with a whole new list or setting it to Nothing, but there's nothing to stop them from doing something like...

```
someInstance.SomeList.Clear()
someInstance.SomeList.AddRange(newListOfStuff)
```

If you really want to restrict what the caller can do with it, you can leave the list private and just implement methods to let the caller do what you want to allow them to do...

```
Private _SomeList As New List(Of Int32)
Public Sub AddToSomeList(val As Int32)
    _SomeList.Add(val)
End Sub
```

Now the caller can add to the list but not remove or clear the list.